# Why is Montreal airport code YUL?

Tags: airports, montreal

I get the Y is for Canadian airports, but while YVR comes from **V**ancouve**r**, YOW for **O**tta**w**a for example I don't see what UL can relate to. Is it just a meaningless acronym ?

Edit: I'm not asking why they start with Y, that seems a convention, but rather what does the UL relate to

Comment: The other question doesn't answer what I want to know, it only explains where the Y comes from. How's that a duplicate ?

Comment: @pnuts that's an assumption I couldn't verify elsewhere